# Excel VBA Countif with Multiple ranges

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I am trying to create a program that finds duplicates in a large excel sheet.

However this sheet has gaps in the data for labeling purposes as the data is entered by month and by person. I need to find a way to highlight and count the number of duplicates.

I have got it to highlight duplicates in one range using

`If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range1, Cell) > 1 Then`

but I need to get two or more ranges into the countif function. Basically I need to compare data for duplicates in a non-continuous range.

So I have the ranges

`C4:H78
J4:O78
Q4:V78`

How would I add those together in VBA, so all ranges are being compared to each other?

I have tried

`If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range1, Cell),Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range2, Cell),etc) > 1 Then`

and using the `Union(range1,range2)` to create one union of range but that didn't work.

I have summed countif in excel directly with 
`=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"Range1","RANGE2",etc}),criteria))`

However `INDIRECT` does not work in VBA that I can find.

I am new to VBA in excel. Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Add multiple `COUNTIF`s together?

Comment: As stated above: `IF (COUNTIF + COUNTIF + COUNTIF) > 1 Then`

Answer (score 0):

```
If ( _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range1, Cell) + _
       Application.WOrksheetFunction.CountIf(Range2, Cell) + _
       Application.WOrksheetFunction.CountIf(Range3, Cell) _
   ) > 1 Then
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often very helpful

Comment: ditto stuff said in comments